# A better way to render component ? React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need a better way to render this component so I need advice.

Check my code:

```
renderComponent = () => {
  if(id){
    return <Placeholder> { id } </Placeholder>
  } else if(date) {
     return <Placeholder> This is date { date } </Placeholder>
  } else if (testData === 'test'){
    return <TestDataComponent></TestDataComponent>
  }
}
```

Maybe a switch would be a better a way? I am using ternary operator but here is three values... maybe I need to add one more conditional.

I want to say this is work , but just need be refactor and write on better a way.

Comment: Is there a _problem_ with what you have? How would you determine if a given alternative is _better_?

Comment: I think this is basically fine as an approach. You don't really need the `else`s as you're `return`ing just before anyway. And at the end you'd want to return `null`. As those components grow in complexity you'll probably want to extract them to their own components, leaving this parent as something that simply determines which component gets shown.

Comment: A complicated "which component do I render" flow is often a sign there's a missing abstraction somewhere. The snippet shown seems fine, although I'd skip the `else`s to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As you return specific component, so you can use just form 3 if blocks which if had true condition then return the component

```
const renderComponent = () => {
  if(id){
    return <Placeholder> { id }</Placeholder>
  }

  if(date) {
     return <Placeholder> This is date { date }</Placeholder>
  }

  if (testData === 'test'){
    return <TestDataComponent />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ternary operator instead of basic if/else

```
renderComponent = () => {
  {id ? (<Placeholder> { id } </Placeholder>) : date ? ( <Placeholder> This is date { date } </Placeholder>):<TestDataComponent/>}
  
}
```

Or use a switch statement. You need to pass the type or whatever case you want, and it will return the relevant component. You also can wrap this switch in a function. Here is an example switch statement:

```
 switch (type) {
      case id:
        return <Placeholder> { id } </Placeholder>;
      case date:
        return  <Placeholder> This is date { date } </Placeholder>;
      case test:
        return <TestDataComponent></TestDataComponent>;
      default:
        return <>Something went wrong</>;
 }
```

Comment: But please don't, because this is impossible to read or reason about ;)

Comment: It's not clean code and has hard readability

Comment: (Delta the `test` case requires setup since it's a condition, not a value on its own.)

Comment: In that case you can leave that switch condition for test and can use ternary operator for that. Or you could go with only if blocks like @SaeedHemmati